# Optimize SQL Query having SUM and COUNT functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following query which takes too long to retrieve around 70000 records. I noticed that the execution time is proportional to the number of the records retrieved. I need to optimize this query so that the execution time is not proportional to the number of records retrieved. Any idea?

```
;WITH TT AS (
      SELECT TaskParts.[TaskPartID], 
      PartCost,
      LabourCost,
      VendorPaidPartAmount,
      VendorPaidLabourAmount,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Employees].[EmpCode] asc) AS RowNum  
      FROM [TaskParts],[Tasks],[WorkOrders], [Employees], [Status],[Models]
      ,[SubAccounts]WHERE 1=1 AND (TaskParts.TaskLineID = Tasks.TaskLineID)
AND (Tasks.WorkOrderID = [WorkOrders].WorkOrderID)
AND (Tasks.EmpID = [Employees].EmpID)
AND (TaskParts.StatusID = [Status].StatusID)
And (Models.ModelID = Tasks.FailedModelID) 
And (SubAccounts.SubAccountID = Tasks.SubAccountID)AND (SubAccounts.GLAccountID = 5))
SELECT  --*
    COUNT(0)--,
    SUM(ISNULL(PartCost,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL(LabourCost,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL(VendorPaidPartAmount,0)), 
    SUM(ISNULL(VendorPaidLabourAmount,0))
    FROM TT
```

Comment: You are only selecting output from `TT`. Remove `TD0`, `TD1` and `TP1` as they are redundant.

Comment: Those tables are not the source of this issue. It's the query with COUNT and SUM

Comment: If you knew that you should have ommitted them from the start. Many people will simply move on. You are doing yourself a disservice by posting long queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lieven noted, you can remove `TD0`, `TD1` and `TP1` as they are redundant.

You can also remove the `row_number` column, as that is not used and windowing functions are relatively expensive.

It may also be possible to remove some of the tables from the `TT` CTE if they are not used; however, as table names have not been included with each column selected, it isn't possible to tell which tables are not being used.

Aside from that, your query's response will always be proportional to the number of rows returned, because the RDBMS has to read each row returned to calculate the results.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. It seems there is a join that causing this delay - the join with Models table. However, this table contains only round 7000 records, not sure yet why it take that much time.

Comment: @mohammedn - Can you post an execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have support index for each Foreign Key also most probably it is not the issue in this case but MS SQL optimization better works with inner joins.
Also I don't see any reason why you need RowNum if you need only totals.